# Initialize an array with both upper and lowercase letters C++

Tags: c++

```
//Loop to initialize the array of structs; set count to zero

for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    //This segment sets the uppercase letters
    letterList[i].letter = static_cast<char>(65 + i);
    letterList[i].count = 0;

    //This segment sets the lowercase letters
    letterList[i + 26].letter = static_cast<char>(97 + i);
    letterList[i + 26].count = 0;
}
```

//this doesnt seem to work!!!

The entire program, takes a text file, reads it and then prints out each letter used, the number of times it was used and the percentage of occurance...however, my output keeps coming out as:

Letter  Count   Percentage of Occurrence

¿       0 0.00%

52 times....

ive searched all over and cant seem to get this...

Comment: `97`? Better `'a'`... There are non-ASCII systems too...

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: How is `letterList` defined?

Comment: You should write question about problem you are facing, not about code that works fine (if you are looking for code review on this chunk of code there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com )

Comment: letter list is a struct of letterType
struct letterType
{
    char letter;
    int count;
};

Comment: @H2CO3 - since alphabets are not guaranteed by the standard to be continous - how does replacing 97 with 'a' in the for loop help?

Comment: replacing 97 with 'a' didnt change anything

Comment: @user93353: Presumably the specification of the program is that it processes ASCII text files, in which case leveraging the properties of ASCII is quite reasonable.

Comment: @BenVoigt - in which case, using 97 is also reasonable, which is what H2CO3 suggested changing to 'a'.

Comment: @user93353 It doesn't help directly, that's why I put it in a comment, not in an answer. It only makes your program a bit more portable, and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any problem for this codes ouput

```
    letterType letterList[52];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        //This segment sets the uppercase letters
        letterList[i].letter = static_cast<char>('A' + i);
        letterList[i].count = 0;

        //This segment sets the lowercase letters
        letterList[i + 26].letter = static_cast<char>('a' + i);
        letterList[i + 26].count = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26 * 2; i++)
        cout<<letterList[i].letter<<" "<<letterList[i].count<<endl;
```

Comment: this is the exact thing I need my program to do, however I cannot change the printResults coding in mine..

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/53106/

Comment: This code just intialises letterList array and prints it for you. Your function printResults writes the results to a file. change outFile to cout you can see output on console. That code is working for me

Comment: I understand that code is a working code, it is the code that I am trying to base mine off of, I have tried changing outfile to cout however the same output is being displayed. ¿ letter, 0 count and 0.00% for occurance percentage

Comment: Write this code for (int i = 0; i < 26 * 2; i++)cout<<letterList[i].letter<<" "<<letterList[i].count<<endl; in your count function after the while loop. ie just after counting complete. With out seeing cmplete code i cant help you more

Comment: I checked your code @ other lik and posted answer.please check

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0, c='a'; i<26; i++)
{
        letterList[i] = c++;
}
for(int i=26,c='a'; i<52; i++)
{
        letterList[i] = toupper(c++);
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace the second for loop with this:

```
for(int i=26,c='A'; i<52; i++)
{
        letterList[i] = c++;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your requirement to have `struct`
Assuming your `struct` has a `char` member and each `struct` instance carry each letter, this is the code:

```
struct letterType
{
    char letter;
};

int main()
{
    struct letterType letterList[52];
    char c;
    for(int i=0, c='a'; i<26; i++)
    {
            letterList[i].letter = c++;
    }
    for(int i=26,c='a'; i<52; i++)
    {
            letterList[i].letter = toupper(c++);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
            cout<< letterList[i].letter << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ditch `toupper`, use `'A'` in the second loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt any problem with `toupper`? Anyway, based on your comment, I have mentioned the alternative in my answer.

Comment: @SebastianABaker What data type is `letterList`>

Comment: it is a struct of letterType

Comment: I have my full code, minus declarations here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007935/c-code-compiles-but-gives-wrong-output-initialize-function-is-wrong?noredirect=1#comment22829898_16007935

please review this as well...